# How to reformat Backbone model item

Tags: backbone.js

My backbone collection fetches its models without issue.

The model returns {{=calldate}} in the sql date format.  How should I reformat the date from within the model so that the date is readable in the template as rendered by the view? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Date prettification is a presentation-level activity and shouldn't be done in the model. Either add the formatting logic directly to your template and/or, preferably, create a formatting helper that you can call from any template to format dates prettily and consistently.

There are many prettification libraries. Here's one: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: thanks.  I created a helper function and called it from within the view's render function.  the link is useful